# Подключение к БД на сервере

Tags: c#, база-данных, сервер

У нас на сервере есть БД на Postgre, я пишу приложение которое должно передавать некие данные в эту базу данных с множества компьютеров. Погуглил, решения не нашел, поэтому хочу обратиться к знатокам за помощью. Кто уже занимался таким? нужна помощь в подключении к БД на удаленном сервере.

Comment: [How to Allow Remote Access to PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18580066/312041)

Comment: Нужно скнфигурировать бд на сервере таким образом, чтобы к ней можно было подключаться из глобальной сети. @tym32167 выше разместил полезную ссылку. Было бы неплохо, если бы кто-то перевел ответ и разместил его здесь

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, могу предложить создать пользователя в базе данных специально для этого приложения с определенными правами. Например, эта учетная запись будет иметь возможность `INSERT` в таблицу `A` и если требуется `SELECT` из `A` и `B`. Плюс дополнительно в таблице A иметь пару колонок для того, чтобы понимать с какого конкретного компьютера произошла запись.

Comment: а можно ли создать отдельную базу данных, открыть ее для внешних подключений и в дальнейшем из всех приложений обращаться к этой базе данных?